# Google map on android only shows grid.

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a problem where my map activity only shows the grid and is not downloading map tiles.

What I've checked:

1. I have the api key that I got from [here](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html).
2. I've added the reference to my android manifest.
3. My device has internet (and google maps works on the device).

In LogCat I am getting the following messages from MapActivity

1. 07-28 20:25:19.271: INFO/MapActivity(550): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
2. 07-28 20:25:19.271: ERROR/MapActivity(550): Couldn't get connection factory client

What am I missing? How can check to see that my key is the problem?

Comment: The issue was that I placed the "android.permission.INTERNET" line inside the "application" area of the Manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I placed the "android.permission.INTERNET" line inside the "application" area of the Manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a Debug key:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint

That's indeed really annoying as you have 2 different keys to handle and switch.. ( and sometimes forget to make an update on the Market with your debug key!)

Comment: Also mind the if there is some spacing in your api key in your manifest.

Comment: This gives me a different MD5 than I used to register for the maps api. What do I do with it?

Comment: Can't you read my link????
"Paste the MD5 certificate fingerprint of the certificate that you are registering into the appropriate form field."

Comment: Okay, I did that and pasted the generated key into my app and it also didn't work. The reason I asked what to do with it above was because I already did this with a different MD5. Why do I have to do this twice?